# Debug assertion failed. Null Pointer

Tags: c++

I am having this problem when i try to execute the .exe of my application
"Debug assertion failed !, Expression invalid null pointer"

After a bit of googling i think so i know where the problem lies, but have no idea how to solve it.

Below is the relevant piece of code.

```
size_t idx;
// create the initial texture
atlases.push_back(new TextureAtlas( image_names.size()));
// load the texture
for (idx = 0; idx < image_names.size(); ++idx) {
//load the image
TextureInformation *ti = new TextureInformation (idx, folder_location_str, image_names[idx]);
```

During the execution of the code at the line where ti is initialized and declared the values at local tab(in ms visual c++ 2008) are something like below.

```
ti TextureInformation *
idx CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
image_path {npos=4294967295 _Bx={...} _Mysize=??? ...} std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
image_name {npos=4294967295 _Bx={...} _Mysize=??? ...} std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
image CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found
```

For some reason: idx and image shows error here and this only happens during the first iteration of the for loop. Below is the content of ti during the second iteration

```
idx 0 unsigned int
+ image_path ".....Related\PNG\" std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
+ image_name "basn0g01.png" std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
+ image 0x00812830 {m_info={...} m_pixbuf={...} } png::image<png::basic_rgba_pixel<unsigned char> > *
```

This is how my TextualInformation looks

```
class TextureInformation
{
public:
TextureInformation(size_t index, std::string path, std::string name)
: idx(index), image_path(path), image_name(name)
{
image = new png::image<png::rgba_pixel>(image_path + image_name,
png::convert_color_space<png::rgba_pixel>());
}
~TextureInformation(void)
{
delete image;
}
....
....
private:
size_t idx;
std::string image_path;
std::string image_name;
png::image<png::rgba_pixel>* image;
};
```

Please tell me if other details are required. Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just run this in your debugger to see what the problem is ?

Comment: In your debugger output I think you are confusing the idx, image_path and image_name that are members of the TextureInformation class with the local variables of the same name. Of crouse when you break on the 'load the image' line for the first time `ti` has not been initialised so the debugger is going to show you garbage value for the members of that class. I would be more concerned if you saw garbage if you break on the next line. I don't think you've found the cause of your bug. It's something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks John, I think so you are right. I am beginning to realize it is something totally different

Comment: no, this is how i am doing output_image[out_y][out_x] = (*image)[rot_y][rot_x]; in the for loop and then output_image.write(output_image.write(output_image_name););